# How to load csv file in spark in right way?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am loading csv file in spark but it consists of null values bcz of that arrAy index out of bound exception occurs how to load it?

```
val schema = StructType (Array(StructField("ROW_ID",StringType,true) ,StructField("CREATED",TimestampType,true) ,StructField("CREATED_BY", StringType, true) ,StructField("LAST_UPD",TimestampType,true) ,StructField("LAST_UPD_BY", StringType, true) ,StructField("MODIFICATION_NUM", StringType, true) ,StructField("CONFLICT_ID",StringType, true) ,StructField("ACTIVE_FLG", StringType, true) ,StructField("ALW_PART_SHIP_FLG", StringType, true) ,StructField("APPROVED_FLG", StringType, true) ,StructField("AUTO_RECV_FLG", StringType, true) ,StructField("BILLABLE_FLG", StringType, true) ,StructField("BU_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("CRDT_CHK_PASSD_FLG", StringType, true) ,StructField("DISPLAY_LINE_FLG", StringType, true) ,StructField("DOCNUM_GNRTD_FLG", StringType, true) ,StructField("EXMPT_APP_FLG", StringType, true) ,StructField("EXP_TO_ICTXN_FLG", StringType, true) ,StructField("FREEZE_FLG", StringType, true) ,StructField("FULFIL_LOCKED_FLG", StringType, true) ,StructField("HOLD_FLG", StringType, true) ,StructField("MANUAL_FLG", StringType, true) ,StructField("NEED_NETCHANGE_FLG", StringType, true) ,StructField("ORDER_CAT_CD", StringType, true) ,StructField("ORDER_NUM", StringType, true) ,StructField("ORDER_TYPE_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("PR_REP_DNRM_FLG", StringType, true) ,StructField("PR_REP_MANL_FLG", StringType, true) ,StructField("PR_REP_SYS_FLG", StringType, true) ,StructField("REV_NUM", StringType, true) ,StructField("STATUS_CHG_FLG", StringType, true) ,StructField("TAX_EXEMPT_FLG", StringType, true) ,StructField("TEST_ORDER_FLG", StringType, true) ,StructField("TRACK_REV_FLG", StringType, true) ,StructField("ASGN_TS", StringType, true) ,StructField("CHRG_CREATED_FLG", StringType, true) ,StructField("CMPNS_STATUS_DT", StringType, true) ,StructField("CRCHK_ANN_INCOME", StringType, true) ,StructField("CRCHK_CRDT_SCORE", StringType, true) ,StructField("CRCHK_DATE", StringType, true) ,StructField("CRCHK_PSTPAID_SVC", StringType, true) ,StructField("CRDT_ASGN_TS", StringType, true) ,StructField("CRDT_CRD_EXP_DT", StringType, true) ,StructField("CRDT_CRD_TXN_AMT", StringType, true) ,StructField("CRDT_CRD_TXN_DT", StringType, true) ,StructField("DB_LAST_UPD", TimestampType, true) ,StructField("DISCNT_AMT",StringType, true) ,StructField("DISCNT_PERCENT", StringType, true) ,StructField("DISCNT_RC_AMT", StringType, true) ,StructField("DISCNT_RC_PCT", StringType, true) ,StructField("EAI_SYNC_DT", StringType, true) ,StructField("FRGHT_AMT", StringType, true) ,StructField("FRGHT_AMT_DT", StringType, true) ,StructField("INIT_APRV_AMT", StringType, true) ,StructField("LAST_CANCEL_DT", StringType, true) ,StructField("LOAD_NUM",StringType, true ) ,StructField("ORDER_DT", TimestampType, true) ,StructField("ORDER_EXCH_DT", TimestampType, true)  ,StructField("PRICING_DT", TimestampType, true) ,StructField("PURCH_ORD_EXP_TS", StringType, true) ,StructField("REQ_SHIP_DT", TimestampType, true) ,StructField("REVISION_DT", StringType, true) ,StructField("STATUS_DT",TimestampType, true) ,StructField("TAX_AMT", StringType, true) ,StructField("TAX_AMT_EXCH_DT", StringType, true) ,StructField("TAX_PERCENT", StringType, true) ,StructField("TOTAL_AMT", StringType, true) ,StructField("TOT_EXTND_PRICE", StringType, true) ,StructField("TOT_EXTND_TAX", StringType, true) ,StructField("TOT_QTY_BONUS", StringType, true) ,StructField("TOT_QTY_SHIP", StringType, true) ,StructField("ACCNT_ADDR_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("ACCNT_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("ACCNT_ORDER_NUM", StringType, true) ,StructField("AGREE_BNFT_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("AGREE_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("APPR_BY_EMP_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("APPR_BY_POSTN_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("BILL_ACCNT_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("BILL_PROFILE_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("BLOCK_BL_CD", StringType, true) ,StructField("BLOCK_DLVRY_CD", StringType, true) ,StructField("BL_ADDR_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("BL_CON_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("BL_OU_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("BL_PER_ADDR_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("CAMP_CON_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("CARRIER_CD", StringType, true) ,StructField("CARRIER_PRIO_CD", StringType, true) ,StructField("CCNUM_ENCRPKEY_REF", StringType, true) ,StructField("CCVNUM_ENCRPKY_REF", StringType, true) ,StructField("CCV_NUMBER", StringType, true) ,StructField("CC_NUMBER", StringType, true) ,StructField("CC_TXNPROC_AC_NUM",StringType, true) ,StructField("CC_TXNPROC_VNDR_ID",StringType, true) ,StructField("CC_TXN_RTRN_MSG_CD",StringType, true) ,StructField("CMPND_PROD_NUM",StringType, true) ,StructField("CMPNS_STATUS_CD",StringType, true) ,StructField("COMMIT_TYPE_CD", StringType, true) ,StructField("COMPOUND_PROD_NUM", StringType, true) ,StructField("CONTACT_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("CO_BUS_AREA_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("CRCHK_CRDT_AGENCY", StringType, true) ,StructField("CRCHK_DECISION_CD", StringType, true) ,StructField("CRCHK_IDENTIFIER", StringType, true) ,StructField("CRCHK_ID_TYPE_CD", StringType, true) ,StructField("CRCHK_UPD_BY", StringType, true) ,StructField("CRDHOLDER_NAME", StringType, true) ,StructField("CRDTCD_TXN_STAT_CD", StringType, true) ,StructField("CRDT_CRD_APPR_CD", StringType, true) ,StructField("CRDT_CRD_EXP_MO_CD", StringType, true) ,StructField("CRDT_CRD_EXP_YR_CD", StringType, true) ,StructField("CRDT_CRD_NAME", StringType, true) ,StructField("CRDT_STATUS_CD", StringType, true) ,StructField("CURCY_CD", StringType, true) ,StructField("CUSTOMER_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("DB_LAST_UPD_SRC", StringType, true) ,StructField("DCP_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("DEST_INVLOC_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("DLVRY_PERIOD_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("DLVRY_STATUS_CD", StringType, true) ,StructField("EAI_EXPRT_STAT_CD", StringType, true) ,StructField("EAI_ORDER_NUM", StringType, true) ,StructField("ENTLMNT_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("EVT_SRC_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("FRGHT_AMT_CURCY_CD", StringType, true) ,StructField("FRGHT_TERMS_CD", StringType, true) ,StructField("FRGHT_TERMS_INFO", StringType, true) ,StructField("INTEGRATION_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("LOY_MEMBER_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("LOY_PROMO_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("OPTY_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("PAR_ORDER_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("PAYMENT_TERM_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("PAYMENT_TYPE_CD", StringType, true) ,StructField("PAYTO_ADDR_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("PAYTO_CON_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("PAYTO_OU_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("PAY_AUTH_NUM", StringType, true) ,StructField("PAY_OU_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("PEC_WF_PROC_NAME", StringType, true) ,StructField("PRIO_CD", StringType, true) ,StructField("PRI_LST_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("PRI_WF_PROC_NAME", StringType, true) ,StructField("PROJ_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("PROMO_DCP_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("PROMO_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("PRSP_CONTACT_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("PR_PAYMENT_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("PR_POSTN_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("PR_SHIPMENT_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("QUOTE_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("RTRN_ADDR_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("RTRN_CON_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("RTRN_OU_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("RTRN_REASON_CD", StringType, true) ,StructField("SERV_ACCNT_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("SHIP_ADDR_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("SHIP_CON_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("SHIP_METH_CD", StringType, true) ,StructField("SHIP_OU_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("SHIP_PER_ADDR_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("SLS_HIER_VER_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("SRC_INVLOC_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("SRV_PROV_OU_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("SR_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("STATUS_CD", StringType, true) ,StructField("TAX_AMT_CURCY_CD", StringType, true) ,StructField("TAX_EXEMPT_NUM", StringType, true) ,StructField("TAX_EXEMPT_REASON", StringType, true) ,StructField("TAX_LIST_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("VALIDATION_RULE_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("X_IPTV_FLG", StringType, true) ,StructField("X_TRIAL_FLG", StringType, true) ,StructField("X_ACC_CAT", StringType, true) ,StructField("X_HSBA_BTU_FLG", StringType, true) ,StructField("X_NT_ORDR", StringType, true) ,StructField("X_COMMISSION_TO_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("X_COMMISSION_TO_NAME", StringType, true) ,StructField("X_AE_ID", StringType, true) ,StructField("X_CUST_ABBR", StringType, true) ,StructField("X_URGENT_FLG", StringType, true) ,StructField("DOC_NUM", StringType, true) ,StructField("CRDT_COMMENTS", StringType, true) ,StructField("COMMENTS", StringType, true) ,StructField("DESC_TEXT", StringType, true) ,StructField("DISCNT_REASON", StringType, true) ,StructField("SHIP_INSTRUCTIONS", StringType, true) ,StructField("HOLD_REASON", StringType, true) ,StructField("EAI_ERROR_TEXT", StringType, true)))        


val rowRDD = order.map(_.split("#CO1D#", -1)).map(p => Row(p(0).trim, p(1).trim,p(2).trim,p(3).trim,p(4).trim,p(5).trim,p(6).trim,p(7).trim,p(8).trim,p(9).trim,p(10).trim,p(11).trim,p(12).trim,p(13).trim,p(14).trim,p(15).trim,p(16).trim,p(17).trim,p(18).trim,p(19).trim,p(20).trim,p(21).trim,p(22).trim,p(23).trim,p(24).trim,p(25).trim,p(26).trim,p(27).trim,p(28).trim,p(29).trim,p(30).trim,p(31).trim,p(32).trim,p(33).trim,p(34).trim,p(35).trim,p(36).trim,p(37).trim,p(38).trim,p(39).trim,p(40).trim,p(41).trim,p(42).trim,p(43).trim,p(44).trim,p(45).trim,p(46).trim,p(47).trim,p(48).trim,p(49).trim,p(50).trim,p(51).trim,p(52).trim,p(53).trim,p(54).trim,p(55).trim,p(56).trim,p(57).trim,p(58),p(59).trim,p(60).trim,p(61).trim,p(62).trim,p(63).trim,p(64).trim,p(65).trim,p(66).trim,p(67).trim,p(68).trim,p(69).trim,p(70).trim,p(71).trim,p(72).trim,p(73).trim,p(74).trim,p(75).trim,p(76).trim,p(77).trim,p(78).trim,p(79).trim,p(80).trim,p(81).trim,p(82).trim,p(83).trim,p(84).trim,p(85).trim,p(86).trim,p(87).trim,p(88).trim,p(89).trim,p(90).trim,p(91).trim,p(92).trim,p(93).trim,p(94).trim,p(95).trim,p(96).trim,p(97).trim,p(98).trim,p(99).trim,p(100).trim,p(101).trim,p(102).trim,p(103).trim,p(104).trim,p(105).trim,p(106).trim,p(107).trim,p(108).trim,p(109).trim,p(110).trim,p(111).trim,p(112).trim,p(113).trim,p(114).trim,p(115).trim,p(116).trim,p(117).trim,p(118).trim,p(119).trim,p(120).trim,p(121).trim,p(122).trim,p(123).trim,p(124).trim,p(125).trim,p(126).trim,p(127).trim,p(128).trim,p(129).trim,p(130).trim,p(131).trim,p(132).trim,p(133).trim,p(134).trim,p(135).trim,p(136).trim,p(137).trim,p(138).trim,p(139).trim,p(140).trim,p(141).trim,p(142).trim,p(143).trim,p(144).trim,p(145).trim,p(146).trim,p(147).trim,p(148).trim,p(149).trim,p(150).trim,p(151).trim,p(152).trim,p(153).trim,p(154).trim,p(155).trim,p(156).trim,p(157).trim,p(158).trim,p(159).trim,p(160).trim,p(161).trim,p(162).trim,p(163).trim,p(164).trim,p(165).trim,p(166).trim,p(167).trim,p(168).trim,p(169).trim,p(170).trim,p(171).trim,p(172).trim,p(173).trim,p(174).trim,p(175).trim,p(176).trim,p(177).trim,p(178).trim,p(179).trim,p(180).trim,p(181).trim,p(182).trim,p(183).trim,p(184).trim,p(185).trim,p(186).trim,p(187).trim,p(188).trim,p(189).trim))

val s_order = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD,schema)

s_order.registerTempTable("s_order")
```

error : array index bound out of exception

Comment: i have created schema and use a split function based on column delimiter and  created data frame and registered temp table

Answer (score 1):

I think you can really simplify your "rowRDD" creation. The index out of bounds exceptions is probably because you have empty values at the end of your line, so you can just pad the array to a certain size after splitting.
Apart from that, since it seems like you are taking all of the fields after splitting, you can create your rowRDD like this (change the 190 to the correct length):

```
val rowRDD = order
.map{line => 
    line.split("#CO1D#").map(_.trim).padTo(190, null)
}
.map(Row(_:_*))
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

```
val intColumns = Set(1, 10, 15)
val tsColumns = Set(5, 15)

val rowRDD = order
    .map{line => 
        line.split("#CO1D#").map(_.trim).padTo(190, null)
    }
    .map(fields => {
        val fieldsWithTypes = fields.zipWithIndex.map{ case (s,i) => 
            if (intColumns.contains(i)) {
                s.toInt
            } else if (tsColumns.contains(i)) {
                s.toLong
            } else {
                s
            }
        }
        Row(fieldsWithTypes:_*)
    })
```

The zipWithIndex method is not the most efficient way to iterate the array with index, but looks more convenient to me because of readability.

Comment: i am having small dout if i use padTo every column is taking as stringType . how to mention integer and timestampvalues

Comment: You can do that in the second "map" (the one that creates a Row), but since you have so many columns, it will either require to define them manually, or if you know the index of your integer / timestamp values, you can kind of make it automatically. I edited the answer. If it worked for you, can you please accept it? :)